# nested if loop is not returning the correct output

Tags: python

I am trying to apply the following function to print different colors based on a simple logic. I used nested loop to print black but some how it is not returning it as I wanted.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['date1', 'date1', 'date1', 'date2','date2', 'date2', 'date3', 'date3', 'date3' ],
          'A': ['m', 'm', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'e'],
          'B':['p', 'p', 0, 'p', 'q', 'r', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
          'C':[1,1,0,0,1,0, 0, 0, 1]})



def my_func(A, C):
    if A == "a" and C ==0:
        if A == 'm' and C ==1:
            return 'black'
    elif A == 'a' and C ==1:
        return 'green'
    elif A == "m" and C ==0:
        return "red"

df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: my_func(x['A'], x['C']))
```

Expected output

```
0     None
1     None
2    black
3      red
4    green
5     None
6      red
7     None
8     None
```

Comment: Why does your `my_func()` have a `for` loop in it?

Comment: I am trying to apply the logic for each date separately. @quamrana

Comment: But what is the actual output?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? How does the output looks?

Comment: Yes, I think. You have shown what you want as the output. I'm not sure what you actually get now from your function.

Comment: I get the same except 3rd row value is None instead of black.

Comment: I see you have changed everything about your question. That's not good form here. But still, does your original data have to be in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this. The `df.apply()` applies your function to each row in turn. You don't have to have your own `for` loop. Plus one of your `if`s is redundant:

```py
def my_func(A, C, _):
    if A == 'a' and C == 0:
        return 'black'
    elif A == 'a' and C == 1:
        return 'green'
    elif A == "m" and C == 0:
        return "red"
```

*Update:*

Not knowing much about `pandas`, I think that you are ignoring the date column, so you needn't pass that in.

This would be what you really want:

```py
def my_func(A, C):
    if A == 'a' and C == 0:
        return 'black'
    elif A == 'a' and C == 1:
        return 'green'
    elif A == "m" and C == 0:
        return "red"


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['date1', 'date1', 'date1', 'date2', 'date2', 'date2'],
                       'A': ['m', 'm', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'e'],
                       'B': ['p', 'p', 0, 'p', 'q', 'r'],
                       'C': [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

                       })
    df2 = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['A'], x['C']), axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you. But one thing I am confused about - I need to apply the function for date1 independently from date2. Is that happening here?

Comment: I don't think so. How would you know whether its happening or not?

Comment: yes I will update the input. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Now you can see that the 7th row should be None (not black)  because date3 didn't satisfy the condition A == 'a' and C ==0 followed by A == "m" and C ==1.

Comment: I'll look tomorrow.